# Not receiving notifications form discord

Tags: iphone, notifications

I began using Discord about a week ago now. When asking me access to notifications, I denied accidentally. Now, however, I have missed 50 messages from my friends and I'd like to know how to allow notifications for Discord to stop this from happening again. I am using an iPhone 4S running IOS 9. 
Thanks in advance!

ps: sorry if this question has been asked before, I'm new.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Please see [ask] for important info on asking questions.  You can use the search function to find answers already provided for turning on/off notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first denied an app permission to send notifications this can be fixed very easily in settings. Go to settings. Then click the notifications. Then click discord. Then you can choose to turn notifications on.

There are several types?

**Banners** - This will notify you when a message is sent using a banner.
**Alert** - This appears on the screen and requires an action before continuing

Hope this helps!